# abrir um view em nova aba

Tags: php, mvc

Eu tenho uma `view` com um gráfico, mas não quero que ela abra dentro do meu `template` e sim em uma nova `aba`.

```
$this->loadGrafico('graficoEscola', $grafico);
```

Comment: Existe uma resposta para o que você está querendo. Creio que isso te ajuda a resolver teu problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778670/codeigniter-load-view-in-new-tab

Answer (score 1):

Tens que adicionar o atributo `target` à tag âncora `<a>` e atribuir o valor do atributo como `_blank` para abrir em uma nova `aba`.

Seria algo do tipo:

```
<a target="_blank" href='graficoEscola'>$grafico</a>
```

No próprio formulário, podes obter o mesmo resultado:

```
<form action="#" method="get" target="_blank">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: eu estou utilizando MVC.
 Quando recebo os dados de um formulario via get eu chamo uma função que me retorna uma consulta e mando esse resultado via array($grafico) para meu view que gera um grafico. 

Eu mando esse array chamando meu view dessa forma:

$this->loadGrafico('graficoEscola', $grafico);

Como eu vou usar target nisso?

Comment: Usas o target no teu template.

Comment: nao entendi nada.

Eu tenho um formulário onde e preenchido alguns dados que servem como parâmetros na minha consulta e com isso eu obtenho os dados para gerar um gráfico. quando eu recebo esses dados eu estou carregando a visualização deste gráfico usando $ this-> load-> view ();

Entende? Só que eu nao sei como carregar essa visualização em outra aba. 

Como fazer o $this->loadGrafico('graficoEscola', $grafico); abrir em uma nova aba fora do meu template?

Comment: Resposta editada. Espero que ajude. Recomendo também que dê uma vista de olhos no link disponibilizado na resposta do @JoseRibamar.